# Do we have to plan child birth time based on good future or based on muhurtha?

Tags: astrology

If a woman is pregnant and is ready to give birth then what needs to be considered for the benefit of child?

Is it the time when if they born will enjoy the life or good muhurtha like no varjya, no raahu etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think if there's in scriptural reference about time of delivery cause it's almost impossible for anyone knowingly pre or postponed the delivery without putting both the mother and child in danger. But it's said that one can choose the right time for impregnation.

Sri Shiva Gita 8.9-10.:

> If a woman gets impregnated on her sixteenth day of fertility period, her son would become as majestic as a king or emperor, there's no doubt in that. On the day of 'Rutusnana' (4th day) whichever man's face a lady stares with desire, her offspring would carry that man's characteristics if coition done on 4th day by her husband. That's why on the fourth day of menses cycle, a woman should only look at her husband's face.

> This is the reason why scholars and the 'Kamashashtram' prohibit copulation on the 4th day. If done; the progeny would be short-lived, or beggar or untidy one or an atheist. As per the scripture 'Kamashashtram' if coition done on the 5th day, it produces a girl child with good character, 6th day gives a son with good character, 7th and 8th days give a daughter and son respectively who would be very rich, 9th and 10th days would give a daughter and son respectively who would remain highly pious and sacred, 11th day would produce a highly beautiful daughter, 12th day would bestow a son with a long lifespan, 13th day would produce a prostitute kind of daughter, 14th day would produce a son with good qualities, 15th day would bless with a daughter who would be righteous and spiritual, 16th day would bless with a son who would be a Gyani (wise), long lived, rich and royal. These are the detailed rules of uniting during the fertility period of sixteen days. After these sixteen days uniting with the wife would be useless. Hence a person who unites with his wedded wife only during her fertility period of sixteen days and after that if he abstains from copulation, then such a man is called as a 'Brahmachari (celibate)' by scriptures. So, even a householder can be called as a celibate if he follows the aforementioned rule strictly.

I hope this helps. Prd..